# R - Count rows in dataframe with NA/"" in columns, and total value column

Tags: r

I have a datafrane like this:

```
df = data.frame (Ref  = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                  start_date = c("01/01/20", "02/04/21", NA, NA),
                  text = c("foo", NA, "bar", "foo"),
                  value= c(1000, 7000, 500, 200)
                  )
```

[image]

I want a dataframe that counts the number of NA or BLANK in a column and totals the value column.

So far, I have the following code:

```
naDF = colSums(is.na(df)|df == '')
naDF = data.frame(as.list(naDF))
naDF = melt(naDF)
```

Which produces this:

[image]

But I want another column which totals the value column for those counts e.g.

[image]

Any advice? Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or with `base R`

```
m1 <- df$value * NA^!is.na(df)
data.frame(total_value = colSums(m1, na.rm = TRUE),
    value= colSums(!is.na(m1)))
```

-output

```
            total_value value
Ref                  0     0
start_date         700     2
text              7000     1
value                0     0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a <- df$value * is.na(df)
data.frame(value = colSums(a>0), total_value = colSums(a))

           value total_value
Ref            0           0
start_date     2         700
text           1        7000
value          0           0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(value1 = value) %>%
  pivot_longer(-value1, values_to = 'res',
               values_transform = as.character)%>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(is.na(res)),
            total_value = sum(is.na(res)*value1))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  name       value total_value
  <chr>      <int>       <dbl>
1 Ref            0           0
2 start_date     2         700
3 text           1        7000
4 value          0           0
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ sum(value[is.na(.x)]) * NA^is.na(.x))) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'variable', values_to = 'total_value') %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(is.na(total_value)), total_value = first(total_value))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  variable   value total_value
  <chr>      <int>       <dbl>
1 Ref            0           0
2 start_date     2         700
3 text           1        7000
4 value          0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach using `purrr` package to count the NAs in each column:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  purrr::map_df(~sum(is.na(.))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  bind_cols(total_value = df$value)
```

```
  name       value total_value
  <chr>      <int>       <dbl>
1 Ref            0        1000
2 start_date     2        7000
3 text           1         500
4 value          0         200
```